# Run Sitecore scheduled task (powershell script) same time every day

Tags: powershell, sitecore, sitecore8

I have a sitecore powershell script that I need to run every day at the same time.  As everyone knows, this isn't possible out of the box.  I have read on this site and other blogs that one way to get around it is by updating the "last run" time of the task to the desired time at the end of the task.  Is it possible to update the "last run" time of task in powershell?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could write a script for Sitecore Powershell Extensions to update the last run time.  However, I think you would be better off using the [SiteCron module](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecron) for this.

Answer (score 1):

This article will resolve your question.

http://sitecorejunkie.com/2014/05/31/execute-powershell-scripts-in-scheduled-tasks-using-sitecore-powershell-extensions/